# Understanding where vacuum energy comes from in QFT From Peskin & Schroeder

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, hamiltonian, commutator, klein-gordon-equation

I am studying from Peskin And Schroeder's QFT book, and I have managed to understand all the way to page 21, where I proved that the Klein-Gordon Hamiltonian can be written as (eq 2.31):

$$H=\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\omega_p(a_p^\dagger a_p+\frac{1}{2}[a_p,a_p^\dagger]).\tag{2.31}$$

But next, the book states

> *The second term is proportional to  $\delta(0)$, an infinite $c$-number. It is simply the sum over all modes of the zero-point energies $\frac{\omega_p}{2}$.*

But I don't understand how we could see that the term is indeed proportional to $\delta(0)$.

Comment: Hint: $[a_p,\,a_q^\dagger]=\color{red}{(2\pi)^3}\color{blue}{2}\color{limegreen}{\omega_p}\delta^3(p-q)$ (I forget which of the coloured factors their normalization needs; probably all of them).

Comment: Hint: CCR......

Answer (score 1):

The canonical commutation relations obeyed by the creation and annihilation operators is $$[a(p),a^\dagger(q)]=(2\pi)^3 2p^0 \delta^{(3)}(\vec{p}-\vec{q}).$$

The $2p^0$ factor really depends on your normalization convention. When it is there we call it *covariant normalization*, but some authors work with states normalized such that the $2p^0$ is not there.

In either way, $[a(p),a^\dagger(p)]\propto \delta^{(3)}(0)$.

Comment: Thank you! If you don't mind me asking, does this mean that we are summing over an infinite amount (once for each value of p) of $\delta(0)$? Is that why we get this infinity? Or is it just one $\delta(0)$, which is infinite by itself? That part confuses me still

Comment: We are in fact multiplying $\delta^{(3)}(0)$ by $\int \dfrac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}$. So it is a product of two infinities. But even if the integral were finite, $\delta^{(3)}(0)$ is already infinity, and infinity times anything is infinity.

Comment: (Except for $0$; then it's an indeterminate form.)